# npm 3 flat dependency not always applied

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 3 dependencies that all reference esprima-fb, and the version resolves to 15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb for all of them.

I was expecting to see esprima-fb in the top level of node_modules folder, but it isn't there. They are in the node_modules folder of each dependency.

Everything still works, but it means that I cannot successfully ensure that my npm-shrinkwrap.json file is up to date, because the tool I am using expects to find esprima-fb at the top level of npm-shrinkwrap.json dependencies, not nested inside each of the dependencies.

My question is, which bit is behaving in an unexpected way? npm by not installing at least 1 version of esprima-fb to the top level? Comparison tool by assuming that npm will always behave in that way?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same behavior with `esprima-fb` nested under `jstransform`. I don't know why `esprima-fb` was nested, but I also found `node-pre-gyp` nested under `fsevents` which I believe is because `node-pre-gyp` is a bundled dependency (see `package.json` of `jstranform`). A bundled dependency is published along with the module. If you look at the gzip in your npm cache you will find the bundled dependency zipped up inside it's parent, within `node_modules`. I'm calling them module stowaways.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is inefficient, that `npm` does not flatten the dependency (since all three copies of it are in the same version, this is quite strange), this behavior is perfectly valid. The other tool shouldn't expect the dependency to be installed top-level.

Another way how to look at it: what if those 3 esprima-fb dependencies resolved to slightly different versions? In such a case, not-flattening those dependencies is the only option.

Comment: My understanding from https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3 was that at least one of them (the first one npm encounters during install) will be hoisted to the top-level. That doesn't happen here, so I am wondering what is going on.

Comment: My guess is that there is some setting (npm packages have a tons of settings) that either prevents npm from doing so, or confuses npm to behave unexpectedly. If you can afford to spend some time on the issue, it may be worth to find the minimal example which is 'failing' and consider submitting a bug. This said, I still believe that you shouldn't count on the fact that one (which one? just one random?) instance of the package will be present on the top level.